# Custom ms sql query

Tags: sql-server

Is it posible that an ms sql query to return only a portion of what is stored in a field?

For example, I got this data stored in the field:

```
row NGV1="" NGV10="*" NGV6=" " NGV5=" " NGV4=" " NGV3=" " NGV2=" " _tipprodus="NGV" lotuloptim="20" /
```

I only need to display the value that is between the quotation marks from this part `lotuloptim="20"`. The result should be `20`.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards

Comment: Do you have the value `lotuloptim="20"` or the value `"20"` in attribute `lotuloptim`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql), but using substring you need to know the start index

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,start,length) AS some_name FROM table_name;
```

and then you can use [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) to find the index for example to the **lotuloptim** word

```
DECLARE @document varchar(64);  
SELECT @document = 'Reflectors are vital safety' +  
                   ' components of your bicycle.';  
SELECT CHARINDEX('bicycle', @document);  
GO
```